# 2009 MacBook no longer boots after SSD upgrade

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I recently installed a new SSD on my 2009 MacBook and it ran fine for less than a day. However, it stopped recognising the keyboard and trackpad.

As a workaround I tried using an external keyboard and a Bluetooth mouse but now it won't even turn on.

I don't know if the power button is faulty or not, but I know the battery is definitely charged.

I tried taking out each of the RAM modules but that made no difference, so either they're both fried or this isn't the problem. I also tried using the SSD/HDD but it still won't turn on. Even the white light that turns on at start up or during sleep won't turn on. Absolutely nothing.

How can I troubleshoot this further?

Edit: After it failed to detect the keyboard/track pad,  I did put the old Hdd back in. So when it stopped turning on at all,  it had the original hdd in it.

Also important : I had to reset the date (back to 2015) in order to be able to install El Capitan. Otherwise, it showed the error,  'this file can't be verified and may have been corrupted or tampered with'

Answer (score 1):

Take out the SSD and put in the original hard drive, see if it will work then. If not, take it to an Apple Store. They will run a diagnostic to see what's wrong. Don't tell them you've opened it yourself and don't leave in the SSD otherwise they're gonna tell you the warranty is voided. BTW in case you're a smoker, I would also recommend cleaning the inside.

Comment: This all sounds like a good place to start : put old drive back in removes a lot of options as to finding the real problem.

Comment: I did do this before posting. Question is edited to include this.

Comment: Then I would recommend going to the Apple Store with the old hard drive in.

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion in Mark D's answer is a good one as it helps you eliminate one very obvious possibility, although it's not clear to me whether you may have already tried this as you state *I also tried using the SSD/HDD but it still won't turn on*.

Although you're not sure whether the physical power button is faulty, I would still try resetting the SMC to determine if this has any impact.

**IMPORTANT!**

It's not clear which 2009 model MacBook you have, as some models had a built-in battery and others had a removable battery. Below are instructions for both scenarios - so choose the one that applies in your case!

**Built-in battery instructions**

1. Shut down your Mac
2. Unplug the power cable from your Mac
3. For 10 seconds, press and hold at the same time the <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>control</kbd><kbd>option</kbd> keys (on the **left** side of the **built-in** keyboard) ***and*** the <kbd>power button</kbd>
4. After 10 seconds let go of all keys and the power button
5. Plug in the power cable
6. Turn your Mac back on with the power button.

**Removable battery instructions**

1. Shut down your computer
2. **Disconnect** the power cable from the computer
3. Remove the battery
4. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> for 5 seconds and release
5. Put the battery back in
6. Reconnect the MagSafe cord (or power cable)
7. Turn your computer back on with the power button

Once you've taken the appropriate steps, see if you can power up the MacBook. If you can, I would then also reset the NVRAM as follows:

**Reset the NVRAM**

Older Macs had what's called Parameter RAM (PRAM), newer Macs use Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). Here’s how to reset this in your MacBook:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> *and then* press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys. You have to make sure you press these keys **before** the gray screen appears or it won’t work.
3. **Hold those keys down** until your Mac reboots again (i.e. a 2nd time) and you here the startup chime.
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

After trying the above, let us know how you go.

Comment: When resetting nvram, should you wait for 2 startup chimes?

Comment: Not officially, although ever since the PRAM days many have felt that letting it chime two or even three times was better. The reality is only one time is needed to do the reset. Often people count two because there's the initial startup chime when you first boot up your Mac (well, at least until the 2016 MBPs came along), and the follow-up chime when the reset happens. That said, you can keep the keys down and let it zap three or four times - doing so won't cause any harm. Finally, I have seen **rare** instances where users have had to do it again (from scratch) before an issue was resolved.

Comment: Since you asked the question I decided that Step 3 of my reset NVRAM instructions was a little ambiguous, so I've just clarified that a little. Thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: My macbook's identifier is 5,2. Its probably the early 2009 model because it only supports El Capitan and not Sierra. 4gb ram and 2.13ghz.         I did try reseting both NVRAM and SMC. I have a question tho,  is it okay to use the external keyboard for this? The built in keyboard is now completely unresponsive, even the power button

Comment: I understand your keyboard and power button appear unresponsive, but I would try with the built-in keyboard first anyway. The 5,2 identifier was used for the 13" models in both early and mid 2009. The key thing is that they had removable batteries, so be sure you use the appropriate instructions. Let me know how you go. Also, as an aside, if that doesn't work, try also to power up without the battery at all to see what difference, if any, that makes. If it boots, also test the keyboard/trackpad as well while the battery isn't installed.

Comment: @monomeeth I tried both the steps you said again but nothing happened. It wont turn on without battery too. I did these 3 things earlier too when the power button was working and the trackpad/keyboard wasn't. It did turn on without the battery  but the problem still persisted. Maybe I've somehow managed to damage its hardware.

Comment: You may be right, especially if you're sensing that there's just no power at all getting to the computer. When you had it open, did you touch anything else? Did you happen to follow any particular steps while you upgraded to the SSD (e.g. an iFixit page, a YouTube video, etc) or did you literally just remove one drive and replace it with the SSD)?

Comment: @monomeeth I didnt follow any guide or anything. Yes, I literally did remove the drive and replace it with the new ssd, turned it on, and Inserted the snow leopard CD. It showed the setup at startup. I used it with SL for a day or so, no problems, then made a bootable USB of El Capitan (10.11.0) and did a clean install. **Note that I had to reset the date to august 2015 for the installation to start, It wont otherwise** Used that for half a day, no problems. But at this point, I had to upgrade to 10.11.6 and the combo update was in my old HDD.

Comment: @monomeeth I didnt have a usb to sata connector so I reconnected the old hdd and copied. This is where the problems started. When I reconnected the new SSD, It has stopped recognizing the keyboard/trackpad. Thinking it is a software issue, I go ahead with the install to 10.11.6. which went fine, but didnt resolve the issue. So i placed my old HDD back and ran it off that, it still wont detect. This is where I tried to reset SMC/NVRAM and power on without the battery. At this point, the power button was still working but last night, even that stopped.

Comment: This happened right before I was going to reinstall the OS to see If that made a difference. But it has been dead since.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61263/discussion-between-monomeeth-and-abhi-minhas).